# Java Two-Dimensional Array Syntax Wrapping Borders

Tags: java, arrays, math

I am creating a two-dimensional array in Java that reads a number from the user and makes a grid that size. To start the array, I would like to place a 1 in the middle of the top row. We will call this *K*. After *K* has been placed, I would like to place *K+1* to the right and up wrapping around the borders. However, if the position to the right and up has already been filled, OR it is in the upper right-hand corner, then you must move to the position straight down instead. Here is an example of a 7x7 grid that follows these steps.

30 39 48 1 10 19 28

38 47 7 9 18 27 29

46 6 8 17 26 35 37

5 14 16 25 34 36 45

13 15 24 33 42 44 4

21 23 32 41 43 3 12

22 31 40 49 2 11 20

I tried a couple of different things, and I was unable to come up with the correct solution. I have a feeling that divs and mods are used in this somehow but I can not figure it out. If someone would like a good challenge, this is it hahah!

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.  Point out exactly at which point you seem to be having trouble.  When I did this for a simple Game of Life I made, I broke this into two operations.  One was to do things like "up and to the right" and the other was to clamp the indexes to the array size.  Both are simple operations when you do the separately and easy to test.  What testing did you do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written the code to YOUR specifications, AND shown what the grid looks like at each point in the process. It does not come out as your expected result...so either you haven't described the rules correctly, or you've got the "expected output" written incorrectly.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

class Main {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) {   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Size of grid? ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    if (size > 0) {
      int[][] grid = new int[size][size];  
      int max = (int)Math.pow(size, 2);
      int length = Integer.toString(max).length();      
      int col = size / 2;
      int row = 0;
      grid[row][col]=1;
      displayGrid(grid, length, row, col);
      for (int i=2; i<=max; i++) {
        int newCol = (col+1) == size ? 0 : (col+1); // to the right, wrapping
        int newRow = (row-1) >= 0 ? (row-1) : size-1; // up, wrapping
        // if the new position is already taken or is the top right corner
        if (grid[newRow][newCol]!=0 || (newRow==0 && newCol==(size-1))) {
          // then move straight down, wrapping, instead
          newRow = (row+1) < size ? (row+1) : 0;
          newCol = col;
        }
        // put the current number in its spot and update row, col
        grid[newRow][newCol]=i;  
        row = newRow;
        col = newCol;
        displayGrid(grid, length, row, col);
      }
    }    
  }

  public static void displayGrid(int[][] grid, int padLength, int curRow, int curCol) {
    String format = "";
    for(int i=0; i<padLength; i++) {
      format = format + "0";
    }
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(format);
    for(int r=0; r<grid.length; r++) {
      for(int c=0; c<grid[r].length; c++) {
        System.out.print(df.format(grid[r][c]));
        System.out.print(r==curRow && c==curCol ? "*" : " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
  
}
```

Resulting output: Asterisk, *, is to the right of the number just placed!

```
Size of grid? 7
00 00 00 01*00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 02*00 00 

00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 03*00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 

00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04*
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 

00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
05*00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 

00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 06*00 00 00 00 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 

00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 07*00 00 00 00 
00 06 00 00 00 00 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 

00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 07 00 00 00 00 
00 06 08*00 00 00 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 

00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
00 00 07 09*00 00 00 
00 06 08 00 00 00 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 

00 00 00 01 10*00 00 
00 00 07 09 00 00 00 
00 06 08 00 00 00 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 
00 00 00 00 02 00 00 

00 00 00 01 10 00 00 
00 00 07 09 00 00 00 
00 06 08 00 00 00 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 
00 00 00 00 02 11*00 

00 00 00 01 10 00 00 
00 00 07 09 00 00 00 
00 06 08 00 00 00 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12*
00 00 00 00 02 11 00 

00 00 00 01 10 00 00 
00 00 07 09 00 00 00 
00 06 08 00 00 00 00 
05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
13*00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 00 

00 00 00 01 10 00 00 
00 00 07 09 00 00 00 
00 06 08 00 00 00 00 
05 14*00 00 00 00 00 
13 00 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 00 

00 00 00 01 10 00 00 
00 00 07 09 00 00 00 
00 06 08 00 00 00 00 
05 14 00 00 00 00 00 
13 15*00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 00 

00 00 00 01 10 00 00 
00 00 07 09 00 00 00 
00 06 08 00 00 00 00 
05 14 16*00 00 00 00 
13 15 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 00 

00 00 00 01 10 00 00 
00 00 07 09 00 00 00 
00 06 08 17*00 00 00 
05 14 16 00 00 00 00 
13 15 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 00 

00 00 00 01 10 00 00 
00 00 07 09 18*00 00 
00 06 08 17 00 00 00 
05 14 16 00 00 00 00 
13 15 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 00 

00 00 00 01 10 19*00 
00 00 07 09 18 00 00 
00 06 08 17 00 00 00 
05 14 16 00 00 00 00 
13 15 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 00 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 00 00 
00 06 08 17 00 00 00 
05 14 16 00 00 00 00 
13 15 00 00 00 00 04 
00 00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 20*

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 00 00 
00 06 08 17 00 00 00 
05 14 16 00 00 00 00 
13 15 00 00 00 00 04 
21*00 00 00 00 03 12 
00 00 00 00 02 11 20 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 00 00 
00 06 08 17 00 00 00 
05 14 16 00 00 00 00 
13 15 00 00 00 00 04 
21 00 00 00 00 03 12 
22*00 00 00 02 11 20 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 00 00 
00 06 08 17 00 00 00 
05 14 16 00 00 00 00 
13 15 00 00 00 00 04 
21 23*00 00 00 03 12 
22 00 00 00 02 11 20 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 00 00 
00 06 08 17 00 00 00 
05 14 16 00 00 00 00 
13 15 24*00 00 00 04 
21 23 00 00 00 03 12 
22 00 00 00 02 11 20 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 00 00 
00 06 08 17 00 00 00 
05 14 16 25*00 00 00 
13 15 24 00 00 00 04 
21 23 00 00 00 03 12 
22 00 00 00 02 11 20 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 00 00 
00 06 08 17 26*00 00 
05 14 16 25 00 00 00 
13 15 24 00 00 00 04 
21 23 00 00 00 03 12 
22 00 00 00 02 11 20 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27*00 
00 06 08 17 26 00 00 
05 14 16 25 00 00 00 
13 15 24 00 00 00 04 
21 23 00 00 00 03 12 
22 00 00 00 02 11 20 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 00 
00 06 08 17 26 28*00 
05 14 16 25 00 00 00 
13 15 24 00 00 00 04 
21 23 00 00 00 03 12 
22 00 00 00 02 11 20 

00 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29*
00 06 08 17 26 28 00 
05 14 16 25 00 00 00 
13 15 24 00 00 00 04 
21 23 00 00 00 03 12 
22 00 00 00 02 11 20 

30*00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 00 
05 14 16 25 00 00 00 
13 15 24 00 00 00 04 
21 23 00 00 00 03 12 
22 00 00 00 02 11 20 

30 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 00 
05 14 16 25 00 00 00 
13 15 24 00 00 00 04 
21 23 00 00 00 03 12 
22 31*00 00 02 11 20 

30 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 00 
05 14 16 25 00 00 00 
13 15 24 00 00 00 04 
21 23 32*00 00 03 12 
22 31 00 00 02 11 20 

30 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 00 
05 14 16 25 00 00 00 
13 15 24 33*00 00 04 
21 23 32 00 00 03 12 
22 31 00 00 02 11 20 

30 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 00 
05 14 16 25 34*00 00 
13 15 24 33 00 00 04 
21 23 32 00 00 03 12 
22 31 00 00 02 11 20 

30 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 00 
05 14 16 25 34 00 00 
13 15 24 33 35*00 04 
21 23 32 00 00 03 12 
22 31 00 00 02 11 20 

30 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 00 
05 14 16 25 34 36*00 
13 15 24 33 35 00 04 
21 23 32 00 00 03 12 
22 31 00 00 02 11 20 

30 00 00 01 10 19 00 
00 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37*
05 14 16 25 34 36 00 
13 15 24 33 35 00 04 
21 23 32 00 00 03 12 
22 31 00 00 02 11 20 

30 00 00 01 10 19 00 
38*00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 00 
13 15 24 33 35 00 04 
21 23 32 00 00 03 12 
22 31 00 00 02 11 20 

30 39*00 01 10 19 00 
38 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 00 
13 15 24 33 35 00 04 
21 23 32 00 00 03 12 
22 31 00 00 02 11 20 

30 39 00 01 10 19 00 
38 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 00 
13 15 24 33 35 00 04 
21 23 32 00 00 03 12 
22 31 40*00 02 11 20 

30 39 00 01 10 19 00 
38 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 00 
13 15 24 33 35 00 04 
21 23 32 41*00 03 12 
22 31 40 00 02 11 20 

30 39 00 01 10 19 00 
38 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 00 
13 15 24 33 35 00 04 
21 23 32 41 00 03 12 
22 31 40 42*02 11 20 

30 39 00 01 10 19 00 
38 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 00 
13 15 24 33 35 00 04 
21 23 32 41 43*03 12 
22 31 40 42 02 11 20 

30 39 00 01 10 19 00 
38 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 00 
13 15 24 33 35 44*04 
21 23 32 41 43 03 12 
22 31 40 42 02 11 20 

30 39 00 01 10 19 00 
38 00 07 09 18 27 29 
00 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 45*
13 15 24 33 35 44 04 
21 23 32 41 43 03 12 
22 31 40 42 02 11 20 

30 39 00 01 10 19 00 
38 00 07 09 18 27 29 
46*06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 45 
13 15 24 33 35 44 04 
21 23 32 41 43 03 12 
22 31 40 42 02 11 20 

30 39 00 01 10 19 00 
38 47*07 09 18 27 29 
46 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 45 
13 15 24 33 35 44 04 
21 23 32 41 43 03 12 
22 31 40 42 02 11 20 

30 39 48*01 10 19 00 
38 47 07 09 18 27 29 
46 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 45 
13 15 24 33 35 44 04 
21 23 32 41 43 03 12 
22 31 40 42 02 11 20 

30 39 48 01 10 19 00 
38 47 49*09 18 27 29 
46 06 08 17 26 28 37 
05 14 16 25 34 36 45 
13 15 24 33 35 44 04 
21 23 32 41 43 03 12 
22 31 40 42 02 11 20
```

Expected Output from Author's post:

```
30 39 48 01 10 19 28
38 47 07 09 18 27 29
46 06 08 17 26 35 37
05 14 16 25 34 36 45
13 15 24 33 42 44 04
21 23 32 41 43 03 12
22 31 40 49 02 11 20
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! The reason why it is not the exact expected outcome is because I was not clear enough in my post. When the upper right corner is reached, K should still be placed in that spot, but instead of moving up and to the right after K is placed, we move straight down after K is placed and than move up and to the right wrapping the borders. In the expected outcome you can that '28' is in the upper right corner and '29' is directly below that.